# How can I compare rows in a group of one day by using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark

I have a dataset as follows. I want to calculate the duration time (to create a new column) of modes every day.

```
          TS                 mode
 1  2021/9/15  10:00:00       A
 2  2021/9/15  16:00:00       B
 3  2021/9/16  05:00:00       A
 4  2021/9/16  10:00:00       C
 5  2021/9/16  12:00:00       B
```

The expected result is as follows. Because the second row cross over days, I need to insert a new line to split duration time.

```
          TS                 mode     mode duration time(hour)
 1  2021/9/15  10:00:00       A                 6     //16:00-10:00
 2  2021/9/15  16:00:00       B                 8     //24:00-16:00(last mode in a day)
 3  2021/9/16  00:00:00       B                 5     //because row no.2 cross over days, I need to create new line to split it
 4  2021/9/16  05:00:00       A                 5
 5  2021/9/16  10:00:00       C                 2
 6  2021/9/16  12:00:00       B                 NaN
```

I have tried diff(), but it can only calculate the duration time, it cannot solve the "cross over days" problem. The following result shows the diff result.

```
          TS                 mode     mode duration time(hour)
 1  2021/9/15  10:00:00       A              6
 2  2021/9/15  16:00:00       B              13
 3  2021/9/16  05:00:00       A              5
 4  2021/9/16  10:00:00       C              2
 5  2021/9/16  12:00:00       B              NaN
```

In C language, I can do just like this, but how can I do this in pandas? Can someone help me?

```
  for(i=0; i<row.size(); i++) {
     if(row[i].TS.dateTime() == row[i+1].TS.dateTime()) { //dateTime() is method to get date like "2021/9/15"
         duration = row[i+1].TS - row[i].TS;
     } else {
         duration = "24:00:00" - row[i].TS;
         insert(TS=row[i+1].TS-"00:00:00")  //insert a new line
     }   
  }
```

Comment: The `mode duration` column is cut off in the first image so it's not obvious until you look at the second image of what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you could post the data and format it as code, instead of pasting pictures that would be super helpful.

Comment: @KT12 mode duration column is not exist at dataset, which need to create. Sorry for lost of details.

Comment: @Chris I have changed the data as code. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Why did you tag this question with `apache-spark` ? Do you want your problem to be solved using only pandas or you can use Spark ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this, explanation in the comments:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# ensure date is in right format
df['TS'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TS'])

# get list of all possible dates
times = df['TS']
possible_dates = pd.date_range(start=times.min().date(),
                              end=times.max().date(),
                              freq='D')

# combine all dates, dropping any duplicates if present
times = pd.Series(list(times) + list(possible_dates)).drop_duplicates()

# sort times and calculate difference in hours
times = times.sort_values()
_diff = times.diff()/ np.timedelta64(1, 'h')

# shift the order up by 1
_diff = list(_diff)[1:] + [np.NaN]

# left join back to the original dataset
diff = pd.DataFrame({'TS': times, 'mode_duration':_diff})
df = pd.merge(df, diff, on='TS', how='left')
```

If you'd like to do it in a loop as per your C language code:

```
# ensure date is in right format
df['TS'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TS'])
diff = []

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if i+1 < len(df):
        if row['TS'].date() == df.iloc[i+1]['TS'].date():
            _diff = (df.iloc[i+1]['TS'] - row['TS'])/ np.timedelta64(1, 'h')
            diff.append(int(_diff))
        else:
            diff.append(24 - row['TS'].hour)
    else:
        diff.append(np.NaN)
        
df['mode_duration'] = diff
```